# Delphi - Reading Nested JSON

Tags: json, delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I have a REST call that is working properly.  I can pass parameters, it returns data.

The app uses `TRESTClient`, `TRESTResponse`, `TRESTRequest`, `TRESTAdapter`, feeding into `TClientDataSet` and `TDataSource`.

The end result is that when the JSON data comes in, I can iterate through it as if it was a table.  With simple JSON, I can get this working.

I am now querying a REST service which is providing data that is one level deeper than normal. See JSON below.

Everything I need to access is UNDER the `mycursor` element, which is under the `items` element.

I can't change the REST service, so how can I tell one of these components to ignore the `items` level and look at the `mycursor` level?

The data I am looking to parse has a first element of `id`.

```json
{
  "next":
  {
    "$ref":"https://<internal URL>/?page=1"
  },
  "items":
  [
    {
      "mycursor":
      [
        {
          "id":13372,
             …
        },
        {
          "id":13373,
           …
        },            
        {
          "id":13374,
              …
        },            
        {
          "id":13375,
           …
        },            
        {
          "id":13376,
            …
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: How are you loading the JSON into the `TClientDataSet`? Please show your actual code. Obviously, you are going to have to do some lre-processing of the JSON before you load it.

Comment: @Remy, I am not "loading" it into TClientDataSet.  As all 6 objects are tied together, when I RestRequest.Execute (after putting in Resource, etc), the data is then in TDatasource. The loading/parsing is happening within the VCL control itself.

Comment: Like I said, you likely won't be able to do that anymore if you have to massage the data. You will have to download the JSON first, parse/modify it as needed, and then load the result into the `TDataSource`. Unless the RESTAdapter has the ability to do that massaging for you, but you didn't say *which* RESTAdapter you are using, or how you are using it.

Comment: @Remy, ahh... I didnt, did I.  Sorry about that.  It is the Delphi TRestResponseDataSetAdapter.

Comment: `TRESTResponse` and `TRESTResponseDataSetAdapter` both have a `RootElement` property.  Use that property to tell the REST framework where to start returning record values from within the overall JSON. In your case, something like `'items[0].mycursor'`.

Comment: @Remy - I knew about the property, I just couldn't get the syntax set properly...  Thank you.  Submit as answer, and I will accept.